# select2 not showing data preselected in the DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following jquery code for select2 where it gets the tags from the database and display them in the dropdown list, and it is working fine:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#catBox").select2({

          tags: true,
       ajax:{

             url: urlTag ,
             headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
             type: 'POST' ,
             dataType: 'json',
             delay: 250,
             data:function(params){
                return{
                    tag_n:params.term
                };
             },
             processResults:function(response){

                return{
                    results: $.map(response.items,function(val,i){
                        return {id:val, text:val}
                    })
                };
             },

          cache:true
       },

  });
});

</script>
```

The following is the dropdown tag, where I have a foreach loop to show a group of tags already selected by the user.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" name="catBox[]" id="catBox" style ="width:540px">

@foreach($u_tags as $u_tag)    
<option>{{ $u_tag }}</option>
@endforeach

</select>
```

The following is the `$u_tag` array :

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "tag1" [1]=> string(7) "zamalek" [2]=> string(4) "ahly" }
```

Problem : The foreach is not showing the data previously selected by the user  in the u_tag array.

Comment: Did you try marking `<option>` selected? `<option selected>`

Comment: No I didn't,,   It worked ,Thanks a lot.